# Any website or textbook with problems/solutions for Computer Science Theory?

Tags: textbook, cs-theory

The course includes: Regular Languages, Context-Free Languages, Turing Machines, Decidability, Reductions, etc. Do you know of any collection of problems/solutions suitable for a senior course?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Sipser is good text, but I also recommend taking a look at the [Stanford CS103 course page archive](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1184/), which has a lot of great supplementary resources, including handouts, problem sets, and lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

The standard text is probably the [Sipser book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113318779X).  It's fantastic, and the problem sets are quite intellectually rich.

Comment: Do you know of any set of slides based on Sipser's book?

Comment: @DrimadesBoy I don't particularly, but it shouldn't be hard to find. I'd start with syllabi that mention the text. Many professors post their slides by default.