# Theory of computation study material with lots of solved examples-:

Tags: self-learning

eg-: examples to create dfa, nfa, turing machine, pda, regular grammar, cfg problems etc. What is the best resource for it? Any book there? Or any thing else there?

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se]!  Your question is unclear.  What qualifies as the "best" resource?  What are you trying to get out of this material?  What are your goals?  There is not enough information here to even make a serious suggestion about what would help you.

Comment: There are quite a few threads on this on the site for textbooks and resources related to CS theory, for example [Any website or textbook with problems/solutions for Computer Science Theory?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/any-website-or-textbook-with-problems-solutions-for-computer-science-theory/6367#6367). Have you checked these yet, and if the existing resources weren't sufficient, could you clarify what you're looking for specifically? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The resource you probably want is [JFLAP](https://www.jflap.org), created by Susan Rodger at Duke University. It is a software system (in Java) in which you can create automata of all kinds and run simulations on them.

Note that from the link above, you can reach the JFLAP book as well.

Comment: Good answer with visual feedback. I use that from time to time. It has been a while since I used it. Thanks for recharging the memory banks.